# Pyaudio in raspberry pi 3 is not working, even the hardware is detected and correct channel and track number is used

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, pyaudio

Here, i print my device information. Attached a cheap USB audio device.

```
for i in range(p.get_device_count()):
    dev = p.get_device_info_by_index(i)
    print((i, dev['name'], dev['maxInputChannels']))


(0, 'bcm2835 ALSA: - (hw:0,0)', 0) 
(1, 'bcm2835 ALSA: IEC958/HDMI(hw:0,1)', 0)
(2, 'TP6920: USB Audio (hw:1,0)', 1)
(3, 'sysdefault', 0) 
(4, 'default', 0) 
(5, 'dmix', 0)

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
            channels=1,
            rate=44100,
            input_device_index=2,
            input=True,
            output=False,
            frames_per_buffer=1024)
```

But i still got error :

```
Expression 'paInvalidSampleRate' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2048
Expression 'PaAlsaStreamComponent_InitialConfigure( &self->capture, inParams, self->primeBuffers, hwParamsCapture, &realSr )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2719
Expression 'PaAlsaStream_Configure( stream, inputParameters, outputParameters, sampleRate, framesPerBuffer, &inputLatency, &outputLatency, &hostBufferSizeMode )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2843
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "record_sound.py", line 31, in <module>
frames_per_buffer=1024)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 750, in open
stream = Stream(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 441, in __init__
self._stream = pa.open(**arguments)
OSError: [Errno -9997] Invalid sample rate
```

pyaudio link : https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(p.get_device_count()):
    dev = p.get_device_info_by_index(i)
    print((i, dev['name'], dev['maxInputChannels']), dev['defaultSampleRate'])
```

I print out the sampling rate and fix the sampling rate, 44100 to 24000